# Turn IE into WebKit by JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, safari, webkit

My html generated pages is working wrong with IE and correct with Safari. I found out https://github.com/trevorlinton/webkit.js project but it still in development and does not support IE. Does exist another ways  to turn IE engine to WebKit using JavaScript?

I know about Chrome Frame plugin for IE but it is not what I want

My aim to change engine - my pages generated from another program and that program is anonced as partaly support of IE and full support of Chrome and Safari

So, i think - the easist way to solve problem of IE to turn IE engine to WebKit engine by Javascript

UPDATE

I found out a solution for IE  - I made a patch to update my genenerated pages after reverse enginiring of generated pages and scripts - but I like more complex solution

Is it possible to change browser engine by javascript?

Comment: I know about  Chrome Frame plugin for IE  but it is not what I want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing a browser engine from a webpage is a ridiculously dangerous thing even if it was possible. This would open up various security risks because it would allow the engine to be changed to a modified one that contains malicious code, for example, or outdated security technologies.

It is recommended that you actually bother to code with standards rather than just for a specific browser to avoid compatibility issues or broken pages on other browsers. 
Providing all the vendor-specific prefixes as well as the standardized version in CSS instead of just one vendor-specific prefix in CSS will ensure greater compatibility across a wider range of web browser engines.

For HTML, ensure that your code is [validated](http://validator.w3.org/) properly and closes all tags. Doing this will help improve compatibility on other browsers, as every browser engine uses a slightly different way of interpreting the code.

Comment: My aim to change engine - my pages **generated** from another program and it anonced as partaly support of IE